# Multiple versions of Zend ionCube to support different PHP versions?

Tags: php, ioncube

Can I have multiple versions of Zend ionCube running on a server to support different versions of PHP running in FastCGI?

Comment: IONCube is loaded in the php.ini file, so if you have different php.ini files for each version of PHP you are using then the answer is of course YES.

Comment: thank you :)
Thats what I originally thought but then someone told me I was wrong and they would conflict with each other